# Linux checking shell command (bash)

Tags: linux, bash

How can I check if a shell command ends with some text? For instance if I type

```
$ http://example.com/file.webm
```

(ends with .webm) it will be automatically replaced with

```
$ wget http://example.com/file.webm
```

Of course only if command consists of one part.

I'm using `bash` as my shell.

Comment: If you specify a specific shell, such as `bash` or `zsh`, then you may get an answer for how it may be implemented in that shell.

Comment: It may be bash shell.

Comment: What do you mean by ends with some text?

Answer (score 3):

`bash` 4 provides a hook for handling a "command not found" error. In this case, `http://example.com/file.webm` would not be a valid command, so define the following function in your `.bashrc` file:

```
command_not_found_handle () {
  if [[ $1 = http://*.webm ]]; then
      wget "$1"
  else
      return 127
  fi
}
```

When you attempt to run your URL as a command, `command_not_found_handle` will be called with the URL as the first argument. The function checks if the command name matches a `webm` URL, and if it does, runs `wget` with the URL as an argument. (For any other unrecognized command, just return 127, a the command is *still* unrecognized.)